# Maven dependency version conflict resolution: Which is better, adding exclusion, or adding a dependency?

Tags: java, maven

We have a case in our dependency tree where we have two version of the same jar coming in from different sources, the version we want to use is lower in the tree, so maven is picking the other version using the nearest wins method.

To resolve this, We could either exclude this incorrect version from its source dependency, or directly add that version as another dependency in our pom.

I preferred the latter since it is quicker. But I am not sure if that is the best way of doing it, or are their any drawbacks of adding a dependency. So, is adding an exclusion better than what I did? In what cases and how?

Comment: adding exclusion is better because dependency in maven is hierarchical, so if there is change in order then your solution might still give an error.

Comment: Thanks Naruto, but I am not able to get it, if I have a dependency defined in my pom, it would be at level 1 right, then all others should automatically get ignored i believe. so how does the order come into picture here?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to explicitly define your dependency in order to make it clear which version you are expecting through transitive dependencies.

Although you would normally declare only dependencies directly referenced by your code (i.e. you use `import` statements in Java to include classes from these dependencies), it is also recommended to have control over your dependencies resolution via explicit declaration. Explicit declaration will have priority over Maven dependencies mediation.

Exclusions make your build harder to maintain and potentially you would need to replicate the same exclusion over and over if, for instance, the same dependency would be required transitively via other dependencies and every time with a different version (not the one you want). Moreover, exclusions can have undesired effects as it may take precedence when it is not expected.
Declaring it as part of your dependencies makes it clear, centralized and easier to update/maintain in the future.

**Update**: An even better approach is to use the `dependenciesManagement` section, which also takes priority over Maven dependencies mediation, as stated in the official documentation, [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

> dependency management takes precedence over dependency mediation for transitive dependencies

Comment: Adding an exclusion can have undesired effects as it may take precedence when it is not expected. Making the dependency explicit is the way to go.